# Add duplicate elements?

Tags: jquery

Is this possible to do using jQuery?

Lets say I have a list of items, with values attached eg:

1. Item1: 5
2. Item2: 10
3. Item3: 20
4. Item2: 15
5. Item4: 30
6. Item2: 25
7. Item1: 11

How would I remove all duplicates and add the integers from removed duplicates to one entry, with an output as such using jQuery:

1. Item1: 16
2. Item2: 50
3. Item3: 20
4. Item4: 30

Edit: I've found a function to remove duplicates using $.each, but I have no idea where to go from here to store the values per iteration and modify the DOM for the original item.

```
var seen = {};
$('.variety_name').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).parent().remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
```

Comment: **What have you tried?** maybe *WWW.Do-The-Job-For-Me.com* could help you more...

Comment: It's almost certainly possible. Write some code.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a shortcut, but you can have a new array in which you add any existing elements to the value as you loop through the input array. This would just be javascript, not really jQuery specifically.

Comment: @gdoron nice site, I use it all the time

Comment: Build a 2D array and update it as you loop through your original array.

Comment: @gdoron I'm so registering that domain.

Comment: want help...provide some markup or some definiton of your list...and store value's is  a pretty vague concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple modification of the code you provided (with assumptions about the html):

```
<li class="item"><span class="name">Item1</span>: <span class="value">5</span></li>
<li class="item"><span class="name">Item2</span>: <span class="value">10</span></li>
<li class="item"><span class="name">Item3</span>: <span class="value">20</span></li>
<li class="item"><span class="name">Item2</span>: <span class="value">15</span></li>
<li class="item"><span class="name">Item4</span>: <span class="value">30</span></li>
<li class="item"><span class="name">Item2</span>: <span class="value">25</span></li>
<li class="item"><span class="name">Item1</span>: <span class="value">11</span></li>
```

```
var seen = {};
$('.name').each( function() {
      var txt = $(this).text();
      if (seen[txt] == undefined) {
          seen[txt] = $(this);
      } else {
          var val = seen[txt].next('.value');
          val.text( parseInt( val.text() ) + parseInt( $(this).next('.value').text() ) );
          $(this).parent().remove();
      }
});
```

When you haven't seen an item, store the object in `seen`.  When you have seen it, add current item's value to the stored object's value, and delete the current item.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/JyGc9/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an straight way to do it, but I can write something to accomplish that, I can use hash lists(tables) or inject the result straight into the dom; I will do using hash lists:
I can format my HTML to look like:

```
<ol id="mainList">
  <li><input type="hidden" value="5" name="item1"/> Item1: 5</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="10" name="item2"/> Item2: 10</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="20" name="item3"/> Item3: 20</li>
  <li><input type="hidden" value="15" name="item2"/> Item2: 15</li>
  ...
</ol>
```

and my script :

```
function addDuplicates (){
  var main_list = $('#mainList') 
// Calculate the result list of items
  var item_list = main_list .find('input');
  var result = {}
  item_list.each(function (index){
    var list_name = $(this).attr('name')
    var list_val = $(this).val()
    if (typeOf(result[list_name])=='undefined')
      result[list_name]=list_val
    else
      result[list_name]=result[list_name]+list_val    
  });

// render the result list
  main_list.empty();
  $.each (result, function (index){
    main_list.append('<li><input type="hidden" value="'+result[index]+'" name="'+index+'"/>'+index+': '+result[index]+'</li>')
  }) 
}
```